# Object references in WinForms PropertyGrids

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

Say I have a class called `StaffMember` and it has a member variable of type `Position`.

If I have an enum which defines all possible positions, then when I load the StaffMember object into my `PropertyGrid`, I can see a drop-down box allowing me to select from the positions defined in my enum.

However, I do not know all the different types of positions - and they can change from week to week - or even at runtime for that matter.

So I don't have a static enum with positions: instead I have a `List<Position>` which contains the current list which can be added to, changed, etc.

When I put my StaffMember object with a List variable into the PropertyGrid, the Position variable is disabled and I am unable to set/modify it.

Is it possible to get this to work, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong/impossible?

Comment: Not clear .. can you show some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want an UI Type Editor ...

have a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx